# How to find the total number of annotated boxes present in a pdf?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

I have a PDF file that contains several annotations.If you notice the image there are several boxes in [Yellow and Beige](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqk9m.jpg). These boxes can be edited in Adobe Reader. Could anyone help me find-out the total number of these boxes present in the pdf file using VBA?

Also, I tried converting the pdf to word using vba, but those boxes weren't present in the word file; so it didn't work out.

Here is the pdf file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7uN4B3mxUlZMjB1T3BuM0o1VGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Only info I could find that comes close to helpful is https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1850161.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in those boxes is always blue while other text is black. Maybe that could be used.

Another way would be to use pdfseparate from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html, and count how often the string `<</AP <</N` occurs in the generated file.

Or you could convert the pdf to an image and then count the number of colored rectangles.

You could also use one of the commercial tools available for creating/editing pdfs e.g. http://www.pdflib.com/, I believe that one supports VBA.